# How to get "dot addition" in numpy similar to dot product?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I'm somewhat new to numpy and am strugging with this problem. I have two 2-dimensional numpy arrays:

```
array1 = [a1, a2, ..., an]
array2 = [b1, b2, ..., am]
```

`a1`, `a2`, `b1`, and `b2` are all 1-d arrays with exactly 100 floats in them. However, `array1` and `array2` have different lengths. So `array1` and `array2` have shapes `(n, 100)` and `(m, 100)` respectively, where `n` and `m` are arbitrary lengths.

I'd like to perform some kind of modified dot product between them so I can output the following matrix:

```
array([[ a1+b1, a1+b2, a1+b3, ...],
       [ a2+b1, a2+b2, a2+b3, ...],
       [ a3+b1, a3+b2, a3+b3, ...],
       [...]])
```

I understand that `np.dot(array1, array2.T)` gets me really close. It just gives me `a1•b1` instead of `a1+b1` in the desired output array.

What's the most computationally efficient way for me to get my desired array with numpy? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `np.outer` ufunc which is for this purpose:

```
np.add.outer(array1,array2)
```

example:

```
array1 = np.array([1,2,3])
array2 = np.array([1,2])
```

output:

```
[[2 3]
 [3 4]
 [4 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks! np.add.outer is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

As a slightly different, and slightly more generalizable solution than the one above.

If you make the first array look like it's (m, 1, 100) and the second array look like its (1, n, 100) and then add these two together, you'll get what you want via numpy's broadcasting rules.

But that's easy:  `m[:,None,:] + n[None,:,:]`. You can easily extend this to any sorts of operations between `m` and `n`.

Comment: Good answer, but I am curious in what sense would that be more generalizable?

Comment: If instead the arrays were (100, m) and (100, n), the solution is still the same idea.  However I'd have to search the documentation to find if there were some version of np.add that used the first index, or some keyword argument to np.add.outer.

Comment: `np.add.ufunc` works for any number of dimensions and returns the output dimensions in the same order as input.